# How to open a dialog from a MenuBar QML

Tags: qt, dialog, qml, qtquick2

I'm trying to open a "About" dialog from the menubar.

I have a MainMenuBar.qml that looks like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import './dialogs'

Labs.MenuBar {

    // Various menus omitted

    AboutDialog {
        id: about_dialog
    }

    Labs.Menu {
        title: qsTr('&Help')

        Labs.MenuItem {
            text: qsTr('&About')
            onTriggered: about_dialog.open()
        }
    }
}
```

And my AboutDialog.qml:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.13
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.13

Dialog {
    title: qsTr('id_about')
    width: 500
    height: 350
    standardButtons: Dialog.Ok

    Page {
        anchors.fill: parent

        header: RowLayout {
            Image {
                Layout.margins: 16
                source: "../ic_home.png"
            }
        }

        Label {
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 32
            wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
            text: qsTr("Hello world")
        }
    }
}
```

When clicking "About" I get:

> /src/MainMenuBar.qml: QML Dialog: cannot find any window to open popup in.

I suppose that happens because I am opening it from the menubar and not from a window - is that possible? What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out. 
AboutDialog.qml shouldn't be declared in MainMenuBar.qml, should be declared in main.qml instead.

MainMenuBar.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import './dialogs'

Labs.MenuBar {

    // Various menus omitted
    Labs.Menu {
        title: qsTr('&Help')

        Labs.MenuItem {
            text: qsTr('&About')
            onTriggered: about_dialog.open()
        }
    }
}
```

main.qml

```
Item {
   MainMenuBar { }

    AboutDialog {
        id: about_dialog
    }
}
```